# How can I set access to mounted TrueCrypt volumes, and how can I dismount them on logout?

Tags: permissions, login, truecrypt

I have TrueCrypt setup to mount volumes when I log into my work account. However, when I log out and log in to another account, those volumes are still mounted and available on the other account.

1. How can I set access to those volumes? I don't want all users to be able to access them once they're mounted. (They mounted at `/media/volumename` - do I just set permissions on the folder "volumename" before mounting?)
2. How can I tell TrueCrypt to dismount them when I log out?

Comment: Not very well experienced with TrueCrypt, but by default the folder volumename would be accessible by world. chmod o-x volumename would revoke access. However, that should probably stop you from reading it too =) You would need to change ownership too, chown d3vid:d3vid volumename. Still, not sure if it would do what you want. If you need help resetting those changes, just ask.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think you have to only modify the folder's rights and make yourself the owner, so other's cannot see the it.

As for the dismount problem, you can create scripts that will autorun on logout. These are stored in `/etc/gdm/PostSession`. From the GDM reference:

> When the user terminates his session, the PostSession script will be run. Operation is similar to Init and PreSession. That is, GDM will attempt to execute the script PostSession/ and if that doesn't exist PostSession/Default will be run. Again the script will be run with root priviledges, the slave daemon will block and the $USER environment variable will contain the name of the user who just logged out.

So basically you have to create a post-session script, that shall contain:

```
#!/bin/sh
truecrypt -d
```

This will dismount all mounted TrueCrypt volumes.